# Fixing IKEA Stolmen into concrete ceiling

Tags: concrete, ceiling

I am going to install Ikea Stolmen to my bedroom.
It needs to be fixed into ceiling. But i can't decide on which screws/anchors going to use for such task.
I had this installed on my old house but setup was done by someone else. I can't really remember what kind of screws were used back there.
Floor part doesn't require any screws.

Left one is ceiling part and right one is the floor part: [image: ceiling]

My installation going to be identical to this one:
[stolmen http://imanada.com/daut/as/f/s/stolmen-system-combinations-all-parts-ikea-1-section-white-width-50-depth-19-58_floor-to-ceiling-shelving_home-decor_wholesale-home-decor-halloween-nautical-affordable-christian-christmas-decorating-s.jpg](http://imanada.com/daut/as/f/s/stolmen-system-combinations-all-parts-ikea-1-section-white-width-50-depth-19-58_floor-to-ceiling-shelving_home-decor_wholesale-home-decor-halloween-nautical-affordable-christian-christmas-decorating-s.jpg)

My ceiling has made of concrete.
Should i use "tapcon" screws or plastic wall anchors with appropriate screws?

Thank you all.

Comment: For this application wouldn't it be better to use a board fastened to the ceiling with two appropriate fasteners and then use screws to attach the flange to the board. Fewer holes in the concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the few applications where the nature of the anchor doesn't matter much.

All of the forces to move the piece are lateral, and the main factor is the shear strength of the screws. There is no tension pulling down since the piece is fully supported at the base.

Tapcons have their advocates, but I find them difficult to get them just right. I might use other masonry anchors, such as lead anchors, less flexible than plastic.

As long as the screws are strong and the fit is pretty tight, any system should work.

Comment: thanks @bib, that was very informative! yes i am not sure on tapcons. going to use anchors, i think. which length i should use for anchors and screws?

Comment: Shouldn't require more than 1/2" (into the concrete). A simple way to do this is to get a ~1/2" through-anchor, which isn't closed on the end. Drill a 3/4" deep hole (put tape around drill bit to mark depth) and install your anchor. Then, just find a machine screw that matches the anchor and has about the right length. The through-hole nature of the anchor will accommodate any excess length.

Comment: Hello Hari, which diameter works best for my case?

Comment: Choose the largest diameter screw that fits through the holes in the fitting, and then choose the anchor sized for that screw.

Comment: thanks @bib, system also has holes at the floor side. i missed that part. should i fix floor too? my floors are wooden parquets.

Comment: I would. The risk of sliding is significant and if it moved, there could be a tragedy. The small holes in the parquet after removal can be easily filled and should be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I would try Velcro to attach a board to the ceiling--Velcro pile stuck to ceiling; Velcro hook stuck to a single board spanning from one pad to the other or short boards one for each pad; flange screwed to board. No holes to patch when you vacate.

Velcro has extremely strong shear resistance.

Comment: Hello Jim. My load will be heavy when whole system installed. Varies around 80-100kgs. Do you think that Velcro can handle such load? Thanks.

Comment: That load will be pressing down on the floor. There will be no vertical load at  the top. What you have to worry about at the top is horizontal force which will be minimal because the load is pretty much balanced over the feet. If you use a single board have it extend 2" or 3" past the top flanges and have some Velcro there and in between the two supports.

Comment: IKEA probably intended for the top flange to be screwed into drywall anchors in drywall. This would prevent lateral movement. I think the Velcro would be sufficient to prevent lateral movement if there is upward pressure. The only thing I wonder about is whether the adhesive on the other side of the Velcro strips would creep on the concrete ceiling and on the board. I think it would hold and not creep. If it did start ot creep then you could later drill through the board into the concrete and  put in two fasteners.

Comment: Frankly I think heavy duty double sided adhesive strips on the ceiling and on the flange would hold. No board no velcro. But if a board is used and flange screwed into the board,  then probably use adhesive between board and concrete ceiling, no velcro.